# using google maps and geo location of the tweet

Tags: jquery, twitter, geolocation

How can I get the geolocation of each user's tweets? Using twitter API. Any example or samples out there?

Note: I am using jQuery and twitter API. I need to get each user longitude and latitude for the tweets everytime the user sends ones.

Comment: not sure how you're using jquery, expand on that... which twitter API are you using the rest API or some framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geolocaction in Twitter is an "opt-in" feature. Most tweeters will not have opted-in, so they won't have geolocation data. You'll see this as their tweets will have a `<geo_enabled>` tag set to FALSE.

For those that have opted in `(<geo_enabled> tag set to TRUE)` you'll see a fully populated `<geo>` object at the end of the status e.g.

```
<status> 
   ... 
   <geo xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"> 
     <georss:Point>37.780300 -122.396900</georss:Point> 
   </geo> 
</status>
```

See [this page](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/dfbd0b3a9d2aba3?hl=en).